# how can I stop submit button from changing page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a form on my single product page for submitting an image with an order. when the button is pressed, it's supposed to upload an image, however it keeps navigating to a 'page not found' page. this is what it looks like:

```
function add_checkout_notice() {
     echo '<form action="accept-file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        echo    '<input type="file" name="photo[]" id="photoUpload" />';
        echo    '<input type="submit" name="submitPhoto" value="Submit">';
        //echo    '<input type="text" name="test_field" value="stuff">';
     echo '</form>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_checkout_notice');
```

the code in accept-file looks like this:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$testLog = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."log.txt","w") or exit ("Unable to open file!");
fwrite ($testLog ,pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
fwrite ($testLog ,$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
fwrite ($testLog ,$target_dir);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submitPhoto"])) {

    fwrite ($testLog ,"set");
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    fwrite ($testLog ,"is image");
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
    fwrite ($testLog ,"not an image");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    fwrite ($testLog ,"already exists");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If your accept_file.php code isn't being run at all, then that means that you need to change the ACTION attribute on your form to ensure that it is actually pointing to the correct file on your server. You're using a relative path right now, this may need to be absolute (by starting with a /).

If you don't want the browser to do it's default action when submitting a form, which is to "change the page" then you need to post your form using javascript and stop the default form behavior by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).